# Apple TV Home Videos

Tags: itunes, appletv

I'm considering importing my home videos into my iTunes library so I can easily access them over any device in the house.  The one problem I'm seeing is when I add home movies, and I have them labeled as home movies in iTunes, on the apple tv they just show up under the movies selection for my iTunes Library.  I heard you can label them as TV Shows and have a bit more control, but honestly I'd just rather have a "Home Movies" option and "Movies" option to pick from on my main screen?  Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind sacrificing the Genre tag, you could tag "real" Movies with Genre="Movie", and your home movies with Genre="Home Movie", and then browse by Genre on the ATV.

Answer (score 0):

I set the genre to 'Home Movies'.  While they are still intermingled with actual movies when viewing ALL, I peruse movies by genre.